# waiting for processing through bat file

Tags: batch-file, azure, command-line, azure-configuration

I am writing a bat file to initialize web configuration for azure website using [Azure command line](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/xplat-cli/).
here is an example of the command:

azure site config add testConfig=false

after writing this command in cmd, It will do some processing and then ask me for website name and then I have to enter the website name like this:

info: Executing command site config add

Web site name: MyfirstWebsite

I have the following instructions in bat file but it never gives me the wanted result

```
@echo off
echo starting program
azure site config add testConfig=false
MyfirstWebSite
```

I want the code above to execute the statement and then enter website enter name and continue but It always just execute the statement

Answer (score 0):

Try like this :

```
@echo off
echo starting program
azure site config add testConfig=false
start MyfirstWebSite
```

Comment: Did you put the URL like this :  `www.yourwebsite.com`

Comment: No no, It doesn't need the full URl since It's already connected to my azure account, all it needs is the site name only

Comment: Did you try with full URL ?

Comment: I didn't because It will not work, I have already executed the command on the cmd manually and It works perfectly, all what I need is to do it automatically via batch file